# Number of possible combinations in specific cases

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Given a list of objects $A=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ of length $n$, how many combinations which only consist of neighboring objects exist?

Example:
Let $n=3$ and $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ such that possibilities are:
$\{a_1\},\{a_2\},\{a_3\},\{a_1,a_2\},\{a_2,a_3\},\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$

So from what I understand:
the number of combinations that include $a_1$ is $n$. The additional number of combinations that include $a_2$ is $n-1$. The additional number of combinations that include $a_3$ is $n-2$.

So basically $P(n)=(n)+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+(n-(n-1))=(n)+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+(1)$

I am unsure how to simplify from here. (assuming this is even correct)

Comment: I don't understand the condition.  What is the answer if $n=3$?

Comment: @lulu updated the question to include example

Comment: Ok.  So, as a hint:  What are the possible combinations for which $a_i$ is the "minimal" element (meaning minimal $i$)?

Comment: @Nilknarf I've though about using $2^n-$ non neighboring objects, but am not really sure that would work.

Comment: You should show your work in the question.

Comment: Looks like there are $n-k+1$ sequences of length $k$ from a set with $n$ elements. $\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k  = \frac 12 (n)(n+1)$

Comment: @SahibaArora done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick proof that doesn't require anything particularly induction-like:

Since the elements are consecutive, you can always define them by their left-most and right-most elements. For example, $\{a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_5\}$ is uniquely defined by the pair $(a_2, a_5)$, while $\{a_{17}\}$ is uniquely defined by the pair $(a_{17}, a_{17})$.

Thus, the number of such sets is equal to the number of ways you can select two boundaries between elements from the original set, which is just ${n+1 \choose 2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

---

Eg $\{\underset{\uparrow}{\phantom{,}}a_1\underset{\uparrow}, a_2\overset{\raise{1ex}\downarrow}, a_3\overset{\raise{1ex}\downarrow},a_4\underset{\uparrow},a_5\underset{\uparrow}{\phantom{,}}\}$ there are $\binom {5+1}2$ ways to select two from the six boundaries to frame a subset of one or more consecutive elements in a five element sequence.

Comment: Note that $\binom n2\neq \frac {n(n+1)}2$.  Counting this way discards the one-element sets, so you meant to write $\binom n2 +n=\frac {n(n-1)}2+n=\frac {n(n+1)}2$

Comment: Ah nuts, you're right. I really must avoid making rookie errors like that. I think I originally worked on the basis of choosing boundaries *between* set elements, which then gives you ${n+1 \choose 2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ as required.

Comment: Yes, that will do it nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Let $s_n$ be the number of combinations. Then $s_{n+1}=s_n+n+1$.This is because the addition of the $n+1$th object $a_{n+1}$ will bring $n+1$ additional combinations, namely $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n+1}\}$, $\{a_2,a_3,\dots,a_{n+1}\}$, $\{a_3,a_4,\dots,a_{n+1}\}$, $\dots$, $\{a_{n+1}\}$.

As $s_1=1$, it is easy to see that $s_n=n(n+1)/2$